# How to run xpath on specific xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The question is almost same as one of my question here [edit specific xml using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225689/how-to-edit-specific-xml-using-xpath)

But now the problem is different. The xml structure is little different now. The solution on earlier question will not work here.

I have below xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <map key="Request">
        <map key="Headers">
            <string key="Accept">application/json</string>
            <string key="Content-Type">application/json</string>
        </map>
        <map key="Payload">
            <map key="root">
                <array key="req1">
                    <string>puneet</string>
                    <string>taneja</string>
                </array>
                <array key="req2">
                    <string>ratan</string>
                </array>
            </map>
        </map>
    </map>
</map>
```

Below are the XPATHS

```
/Request/Headers/Accept=app
/Request/Headers/Content-Type=json
/Request/Payload/root/req1[2]=singh
/Request/Payload/root/req1[1]=pradeep
/Request/Payload/root/req2=suman
```

I want updated result xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <map key="Request">
        <map key="Headers">
            <string key="Accept">application/json</string>
            <string key="Content-Type">application/json</string>
        </map>
        <map key="Payload">
            <map key="root">
                <array key="req1">
                    <string>pradeep</string>
                    <string>singh</string>
                </array>
                <array key="req2">
                    <string>suman</string>
                </array>
            </map>
        </map>
    </map>
</map>
```

Basically I want to change my xml on given xpaths using xslt. Check out the code at this location [xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpY)

It will be helpful for me to have update in same earlier solution for this scenario as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get paths like

```
/Request/Payload/root/req1[2]=singh
/Request/Payload/root/req1[1]=pradeep
```

working you can add a template

```
<xsl:template match=".[contains(., '[') and contains(., '=')]" mode="step">
    <xsl:if test="position() gt 1">/</xsl:if>
    <xsl:sequence select="'*[@key = ''' || substring-before(., '[') || ''']/*[' || replace(., '^[^\[]+\[([0-9]+)\].*$', '$1') || ']'"/>
</xsl:template>
```

so that code like

```
   <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'Request']/*[@key = 'Payload']/*[@key = 'root']/*[@key = 'req1']/*[1]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>pradeep</xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'Request']/*[@key = 'Payload']/*[@key = 'root']/*[@key = 'req1']/*[2]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>singh</xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

is being generated, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpY/1.

I am currently not sure how to infer from `/Request/Payload/root/req2=suman` that there is an array member involved.

Comment: The new Template solves this issue. Thank you Once again Martin :)